# fuerte rgbdslam problem with eigen

Tags: slam, navigation, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm going to start the 3d mapping project with rgbdslam and octomap.
but I'm struggling with rgbdslam.

I installed rgbdslam from source(using rosinstall)
and I wrote
$ rosdep install rgbdslam

then it said,

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Missing resource eigen
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

there are already many Q&A's about fuerte and eigen problems, but I couldn't solve my problems with them.

[This link](http://answers.ros.org/question/38989/rgbdslam-with-ros-fuerte-installed/) is the answer already suggested.

But in my case, the manifest.xml file of rgbdslam already contains  instead of .
Also, I edited my manifest.xml file and CMakeLists.txt as "http://ros.org/wiki/eigen" says, but it was of no use as well.

Here is my manifest.xml.

```
<package>

  <description brief="SLAM on RGBD Data">

    This package can be used to register the point clouds from RGBD sensors such as the kinect or stereo cameras.

    The rgbdslam node can be connected easily to an octomap_server node to create a memory-efficient 3D map.

  </description>

  <author>Felix Endres, Juergen Hess, Nikolas Engelhard</author>
  <license>GPL v3</license>

  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>

  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam</url>

  <depend package="tf"/>

  <depend package="pcl"/>

  <depend package="rospy"/>

  <depend package="roscpp"/>

  <depend package="rosbag"/>

  <depend package="pcl_ros"/>

  <!--depend package="opencv2"/-->

  <depend package="cv_bridge"/>

  <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>

  <!--depend package="openni_camera"/-->

  <!--depend package="octomap_server"/-->

  <!--depend package="octomap"/-->

  <depend package="geometry_msgs"/>

  <depend package="visualization_msgs"/>

  <rosdep name="libqt4-opengl-dev"/>

  <rosdep name="libqt4-dev"/>

  <rosdep name="libglew-dev"/>

  <rosdep name="libdevil-dev"/>

  <rosdep name="libgsl"/>

  <!--rosdep name="gl2ps"/-->

  <rosdep name="eigen"/>

  <rosdep name="libg2o"/>

  <export>

    <rosdoc config="rosdoc.yaml" />

    <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/nodelet_plugins.xml" />

    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/srv_gen/cpp"/>

<cpp cflags="&lt;code&gt;pkg-config --cflags eigen3&lt;/code&gt; -I${prefix}/include 
&lt;code&gt;rosboost-cfg --cflags&lt;/code&gt;" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lplanning_models"/>

 </export>

</package>
```

And the eigen part of my CMakeLists.txt

```
#############################
# Eigen ####################
#############################
find_package(Eigen)

IF(Eigen_FOUND)

  include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

ELSE(Eigen_FOUND)

  MESSAGE("Eigen package was not found. This is OK FOR ROS ELECTRIC, bad for fuerte\n")

ENDIF(Eigen_FOUND)
```

Do you have any solutions about this?

Thanks in advance! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48298/fuerte-rgbdslam-problem-with-eigen../) by [Oppenheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3432/oppenheim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-14**:
Did you do `sudo rosdep init` and `rosdep update` at some point before?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-15**:
What dornhege says. Is libeigen3-dev installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dornhege, Felix. I solved my problem. It's the problem of code of pcl which was out of date, so i erased it and reinstall it, it worked. Thanks for your kind answer and upgrading my question to cleaner version :)

---

Originally posted by [Oppenheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3432/oppenheim/) with karma: 41 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0